# How can I debug C++ code in Android Studio?

Tags: android, c++, android-studio

I have a C++ project in Android Studio that crashes at some point when running on a device.

The problem is that I receive some assembly dump instead of seeing the problem in the C++ code. Setting breakpoints does not work either.

My `build.gradle` contains the following:

```
externalNativeBuild {
    cmake {
        abiFilters "armeabi-v7a", "arm64-v8a"
        cppFlags "-std=c++14"
        arguments "-DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Debug", "-DANDROID_TOOLCHAIN=gcc"
    }
}
packagingOptions {
    doNotStrip "*/armeabi-v7a/*.so"
    doNotStrip "*/arm64-v8a/*.so"
}
buildTypes {
    customDebugType {
        debuggable true
        minifyEnabled false
    }
}
```

Unfortunately, it's not helping. Did anyone successfully debugged C++ code in Android Studio?

Comment: "I receive some assembly dump" - So you *do* actually have something to debug. Sure, debugging asm can be harder than debugging at the C++ level, but it's not impossible. Does your build include debug symbols? is it a unoptimized (debug) build or a optimized (release) build (looks like a debug build from what you posted, but are you sure that's the configuration you are running?)? What compiler are you using? What debugger?

Comment: @JesperJuhl In my case, the ASM dump is not helpful at all. I'm asking CMAKE to create a debug build, which it does (my code is responding to the DEBUG / NDEBUG macros as intended.) I don't really know which compiler / debugger is used (I'm simply running via Android Studio...)

Answer (score 0):

Follow-up:

I was using some code built with gcc and a very old version of the NDK, while modern versions of Android-Studio use LLDB (i.e clang) for debugging.